# PHP rapid skeleton generator for basic CRUD?

Tags: php, frameworks, crud

I have been tasked with building a simple web based system for managing a list of vehicles.

I am interested to know whether there are any robust, clean PHP 5 frameworks / libraries  that are specialized in doing this quickly.

They should be able to quickly build a skeleton web back-end to an arbitrary data structure with the basic functions:

- Customizable list view
- Customizable edit form
- create/update/delete operations

Nice to haves:

- Multi-user interface
- ACL based rights system
- Localization
- Image / File upload built in

Wet dreams:

- A skeleton CRUD API to manage items programmatically
- A skeleton RSS feed to inform about new items

I am aware most big frameworks provide tools and helpers for this, but would prefer a standalone, light-weight solution that is easy to get into.

Alternatively, is there a great PHP application that you would recommend looking into to modify to suit my needs?

Comment: I'd recommend Symfony, but it's not exactly "lightweight".

Comment: CodeIgniter is another alternative

Comment: Have you ruled out some of tools given in the suitable http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=crud+frameworks+php questions already?

Comment: @Gordon what a charming way of telling me this is a tripli-quadruplicate :) :) I'll take a look, cheers. However, most references point to one of the big frameworks which is not what I'm looking for. I would prefer a standalone solution that focuses on generating a ready-made simple CRUD application without all the bells and whistles... But maybe using one of the Frameworks' functionality is the way to go here, most answers kind of look that way.

Comment: @Pekka I have looked only briefly at the questions. Some suggest frameworks like phpscaffold.com and other libs I've never heard of. I deliberately didnt closevote, because I have no clue if any of these would fit your bill. Personally, I find RAD tools to be deceivers, because the time you gain in the beginning you'll have to spent later to customize the created code.

Comment: @Gordon yup, that is a very good point. The desire to save time often ends up eating up much more.  Also, I looked at some CRUD generators a few years back, and most were crap in terms of the code they generated... I'll go look, and post what I ended up with if nothing else comes up here.

Comment: 2.5 years later: still using (recommending) Yii, Pekka?

Comment: @Arjan no longer using! That's not necessarily saying it's not *worth* using, although I'm sure the market has changed since. I'm not really using much of anything these days, I'm no longer an active freelance dev, and stick to a very limited range of tools in my part time job

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as building skeleton apps goes, nothing comes close to the [Yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/).

From the site:

> MVC, DAO/ActiveRecord, I18N/L10N,
>   caching, jQuery-based AJAX support,
>   authentication and role-based access
>   control, scaffolding, input
>   validation, widgets, events, theming,
>   Web services, and so on. Written in
>   strict OOP, Yii is easy to use and is
>   extremely flexible and extensible.

It also includes CRUD code generation. Headed by the guy who did Prado.

Comment: +1 for Yii framework. It's amazing how fast you can build a simple crud application. One command and you have all CRUD features including filtering & sorting, authentication & ACL!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want a big framework, you could check out [phpactiverecord](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend CakePHP

Answer (score 1):

I've seen awesome demos of the instant blog in Rails and Django and Symfony.

Looking at Zend, Cake, Symfony, Symfony seems the most like Rails/Django.  Check out the 10 minute (yeah, super sped up!) demo.  It's pretty sweet:

http://www.symfony-project.org/screencast/cart

My experience tells me that there's no framework, lightweight or otherwise that you can easily do what you want quickly if you don't know it.  So that's where the tutorials come in.  You really need a nice ORM to avoid all that mess with the DB and or reinventing that with a CMS.  So the best bet is to choose the one with the best docs, the best tutorial + screencast, in the language you know that gets you closest to your requirements by just changing the names of the variables.  I know Django can do all that you're asking with Django 1.2, but with PHP 5 being the requirement, Symfony and it's ORM is my first suggestion.

Yii looks like something I'll be taking a look at right now!  Yii-Haaw!

Here's Yii's screencast of blog making:  http://www.yiiframework.com/screencast/blog/

Not bad so far!  But it's quite a learning curve to get the blog working.  Very similar to Rails.

Answer (score 1):

The best i have seen around in years http://www.grocerycrud.com/  its for codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

[Sapphire](http://www.silverstripe.org/sapphire) has a lot of promise. I have used the CMS built on it - [SilverStripe](http://www.silverstripe.org/) - for a few projects and it's very nice. But I haven't dug into the back-end too much.

From the website:

- Our Object-Relational Mapper takes
  care of your data. Define your data
  model using our simple PHP5 syntax
  and our ORM does the rest.
- Tell
  Sapphire about your data model, and
  you get 3 interfaces for free. A
  RESTful API, a SOAP API, and an admin
  editing interface.

It's not exactly lightweight, but its core is ~1.3 MB but meets a lot of your "nice to haves"

Answer (score 0):

There are several PHP frameworks that meet your requirements (basic requirements). You should use a framework that you are most familiar. If you do not familiar with any framework, I suggest you to use the CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a drop-in admin panel like this too, so far I've 2:

AjaxCrud - http://ajaxcrud.com/

Peek from Code Canyon - http://bit.ly/toKKrB

Love to hear any other suggestions!